# jQuery datatables sorting on ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I am using datatables. 50 records are loaded on page load, other are loaded on mouse scroll through ajax. So on page load I have 50 records, On scroll I have other 50 total 100 and other 50 makes it 150 rows in tables. Problem I am facing is once I click sort it only sort first loaded 50 records and also remove all other records loaded through ajax.

NOTE: I only want to sort on data that loaded in table through ajax, no need to send ajax on sort and get sorted data from server.

```
function dataTables() {
var e = $("#sample_1");
if(e.length > 0) {
    var dataSort = $(e).data('sort');
    if(dataSort == undefined) {
        dataSort = "desc";
    }
    e.dataTable({
        language: {
            aria: {
                sortAscending: ": activate to sort column ascending",
                sortDescending: ": activate to sort column descending"
            },
            emptyTable: "No Data Found.",
            info: "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
            infoEmpty: "No records found",
            infoFiltered: "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total records)",
            lengthMenu: "Show _MENU_",
            zeroRecords: "No matching records found",
            paginate: {
                previous: "Prev",
                next: "Next",
                last: "Last",
                first: "First"
            }
        },
        searching: false,
        paging: false,
        /* bStateSave: !0,
         lengthMenu: [
         [5, 15, 20, -1],
         [5, 15, 20, "All"]
         ],
         pageLength: 5,*/
        //pagingType: "bootstrap_full_number",
        columnDefs: [{
            orderable: false,
            aTargets: [ -1 ]
        }, {
            className: "dt-right"
        }],
        order: [
            [0, dataSort]
        ]
    });
}
}
```

Comment: how do you add the new rows? simple insert it to the DOM or are do you use .addRows() from tablesorter? https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#addrows

Comment: The code above seems quite incomplete. Perhaps you should give a read at https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: @AndTheGodsMadeLove Yes I am just insert into DOM, like $('.loadAjax').append(data.html).

Comment: Adding new rows with the .addRows() method from the tablesorter plugin will solve your problems. https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#addrows - here are some examples of how to use it. enjoy

Comment: Still not work my code is as follows:$rows = $(data.html);
                    $('.loadAjax').append( $rows )
                        .trigger( 'addRows', [ $rows, resort, function () {
                            
                        } ] );